# Find the sequence using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the sequence $(y_{k})_{k}$ that gives rise to the generating function $Y(s) = (3 - s)^{n}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Someone can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Given a sequence, do you know how to write down its generating function?

Comment: What have you tried? People will be happy to help you once they know you've put in some effort too.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Sorry, but I didn't make any interesting advances.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I'd like a type some tip

Comment: Hint: Write $Y(s) = 3^{1/n}\left(1-\frac13 s\right)^n$. Also note that $Y(s)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, so the coefficients of the sequence $y_k$ will be zero for $k>n$.

Comment: Another hint, related to the one given by @Math1000, is to use the binomial expansion for $(a+b)^n$.

Comment: Do you know of a **theorem** that gives a formula to easily expand the **binomial** power $(x+y)^n$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, I do!

Comment: @BrianMoehring Yes, I meant $3^n\left(1-\frac13 s\right)^n$. Moreover,
$$
\left(1-\frac13s\right)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk \left(-\frac13s\right)^k
$$
by the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We observe  $Y(s)=(3-s)^n$  is  a polynomial in $s$ of  degree  $n$. This implies the polynomial admits a representation
\begin{align*}
Y(s)=\sum_{k=0}^ny_k s^k
\end{align*}
Application   of the binomial theorem to $Y(s)=(3-s)^n$  gives
\begin{align*}
Y(s)&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-s)^k3^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k3^{n-k}s^k
\end{align*}
from which we deduce the sequence $(y_k)_k$ is the finite sequence
\begin{align*}
(y_k)_{0\leq k\leq  n}=\color{blue}{\left(\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k3^{n-k}\right)_{0\leq k\leq n}}
\end{align*}